# How to get the length of the <li> elements in an <ol> with Selenium in Python?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have an `<ol>` list in my HTML like the following:

```
<ol id="search-results">
  <li class="foo">-</li>
  <li class="foo">-</li>
  <li class="foo">-</li>
  <li class="foo">-</li>
</ol>
```

What I need to do is to verify that the `<ol>` list contains `<li>` items within, ie. a search query comes up with actual results. My current code is as follows:

```
search_field = driver.find_element(By.NAME, 'query')
search_field.send_keys('Foo')
search_field.submit()

results_list = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'search-results')
assert len(results_list) > 0
```

but I get the `TypeError: object of type 'FirefoxWebElement' has no len()` error when I run that.

Any ideas how to overcome that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your

```
driver.find_element(By.ID, 'search-results')
```

don't return a list but an element. If you want the list with all the **li**, you could use the `find_elements_by_xpath`.

Try with:

```
results_list = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//ol[@id='search-results']/li[@class='foo']")
print(len(results_list))
assert len(results_list) > 0
```

Comment: @Fashinated Happy to help! If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted: stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 4):

Try the following:

```
search_field = driver.find_element(By.NAME, 'query')
search_field.send_keys('Foo')
search_field.submit()

results_list = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#search-results > li')
assert len(results_list) > 0
```

Comment: Wouldn't this still only select the `ol` element? This probably should be `By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#search-results > li'`

Comment: This one also works, thanks! Now I just need to decide which method works best.

Comment: Thank you for your comment!