# Get <tr> tag count within table using xpath

Tags: javascript, java, html, selenium, automation

Im trying to count the number of tr tag rows within the table shown below using xpath:

```
<table class="table">
<tbody>
<tr>...
<tr>...
<tr>...
<tr>...
</tbody>
</table>
```

I tried the following but it does not give me 4 as the result. Anyone can help me?. Thanks.

```
xpath=//*[@class='table']/tbody//tr
```

[Example Script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/htesa.png)

Comment: Please add the javascript code here you have tried ?

Comment: Hey @moufed , i only need the xpath function as im using selenium ide 3

Comment: checkout  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47038152/how-to-get-the-length-of-the-li-elements-in-an-ol-with-selenium-in-python

Comment: ```//table[@class='table']//tr```  will do job just fine for you.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I recommend you to not use `tbody` tag in your XPath as it might not be present in page source but added by Browser:

```
//table[@class='table']//tr
```

Comment: Although i got a different count,  this really helped thank you jason and everyone else for your help. This function counts tr tags in other tables on the page as well. Not exactly what i wanted,  so i had to have it  count a unique element within the tr tag . In my case used the header  associated with the tr tag. The following worked for me:  xpath=//table[@class='table']//h3

Comment: @SpaceTech as an option you could also specify the index of required table, e.g. `//table[@class='table'][1]//tr`. But unique identifier is better approach

Comment: @SpaceTech P.S. Indexes in XPath starts with the `1` unlike `0` in most programming languages

Answer (score 1):

Why do you restrict yourself to using xPath?
If the HTML code is parsed on the page, a simple `document.querySelectorAll(".table tr").length;` would work.
And if the HTML is a string, you can use regex, like so:
`let rows = str.match(/<tr/g).length;`

Comment: Hey Oskar, thanks for your input, im using selenium ide 3 for now for this project.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code - Make sure you are using `find elements` not `findElement`.

```
driver.findElements(By.xpath("//table[@class='table']/tbody/tr"));
```